# App taking splash as the app name

Tags: android, rename

Can anyone tell me how to change the app name? My app is taking splash as the app name on the Emulator since my first activity is splash.

EDIT:
 It takes "splash" as the app name before the app is launched. Once it is launched the right name is displayed.

Manifest:

```
    <uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="9"
    android:targetSdkVersion="18" />

  <application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.sanginfo.temperatureconvertor.SplashActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_splash" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.sanginfo.temperatureconvertor.LoginActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.LoginActivity" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

</application>
```

Comment: Go to String.xml and Change app_name there

Comment: There the app name already IS what I want it to be.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your manifest file under `application` tag change this tag with whatever you want as a app name..`android:label="@string/app_name"`

Comment: That string already references to what I want as the app name.

Comment: @whoadityanawandar check your activity tags in manifest.xml make sure they don't have their own android:lable tag (or at least they have the correct one if you have more than 1 launcher activity)

Answer (score 0):

use the name attribute on application node as describe in :
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/application-element.html

Answer (score 0):

@stylojack_10

Go to the File name String.xml (Project->res->values->string.xml)

change the value of the tag name app_name.
you can even make your own tag there and make change in Android Manifest file under  tag find **android:label="@string/"your custom app name""**

Hope this will resolve your problem

Answer (score 0):

**Solution 1:** (*this solution works most of the time*)

Go to `res -> values -> strings.xml -> appname`, change name of the app there.

No go to Android Manifest and check if it looks like this:

```
<application

    android:label="@string/app_name" 
    .......................
>
```

If `android:label="@string/app_name"` is changed to `android:label="MyApp"`, than change it to one shown above. Your problem should be solved.

---

**Solution 2:**

there was a file called ***OldAppName*.launch**

it is located in **workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.debug.core/.launches**

also stuff on:

**/User/workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.ltk.core.refactoring/.refactorings**

*also a glitch in Eclipse to show old app name instead of changing the name.*